# When I write to file I get ArrayArray instead of screen output. How to fix?

Tags: php

I have a method like below.  Reduced the code to make clear:

```
function somefunction($data){
    $somestuff = createMyGeojson($data)
    write_aa_winter_sports_points_to_file($geojson);
    return $geojson; 
}

function write_aa_winter_sports_points_to_file($content){

    $file = "aa_winter_sports_points.geojson";
    $dir    = get_template_directory() .'/fs_data/aa_winter_sports_points/override_file_for_upload/';
    file_put_contents($dir.$file, $content);
}
```

The `return $geojson` displays nicely formatted json to the screen, however, when I look into my file all the respective data looks to be in `ArrayArray`.  I tried `print_r()` but that didn't help.  How to save the screen to file with `file_put_contents()`?

This is currently my file content.

`FeatureCollectionaa_winter_sports_pointsArrayArray`

Comment: When you convert an array to a string you just get the word `Array`. You need to write code that produces a string in the format you want. You can use `json_encode()` to create JSON, `implode()` to create a delimited list, etc.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!  json_encode() worked for me.  Add it as the answer and I can boost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a string in the format that `print_r()` produces, give a second argument `true` to the function.

```
file_put_contents($dir.$file, print_r($content, true));
```

Or you can write it as JSON:

```
file_put_contents($dir.$file, json_encode($content));
```